# pull data in multiple languages ​in mongoose and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, multilingual

I have such a schema.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

var Schema = mongoose.Schema

var newsschema = new Schema({
  name_ru: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 100, minlength: 3}, 
  name_en: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 100, minlength: 3}, 
  name_uk: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 100, minlength: 3},

  desc_ru: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 3}, 
  desc_en: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 3}, 
  desc_uk: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 3},

 created_date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
},{collection:'news'})

var news= mongoose.model('news', newsschema)

module.exports = news
```

When English is selected, only English
I want the data to come.
For example, if there is such a thing, can you help?

```
name = name_en
```

and

```
desc = desc_en
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer as below.

```
newsModel.aggregate([
  {
    $project:{name:"$name_en", desc:"$desc_en", created_date:true}
  }
],(error, results)=>{
 console.log(results)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it correctly, you just want to fetch data where the `name_en` and `desc_en` are present, then why not remove the `required` paramter in schema and insert only those fields needed depending on the language.

In that case, you can fetch data using a simple find query,

```
db.collection.find({"name_en":{$exists:true},"desc_en":{$exists: true}})
```

If thats not possible,

```
db.collection.find({},{name_en:1,desc_en:1,created_date:1})
```

would be sufficient i believe.